# Problema para centrar un contenido

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Estoy tratando de centrar esto pero no lo logro, está en una versión antigua de bootstrap **(v3.3.6)** y no la puedo actualizar porque se rompe todo el template si lo hago, el código es el siguiente

```html
<div class="normal-table-area">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 pd-x-auto">
                    <div class="normal-table-list">
                        <div class="basic-tb-hd">
                            <img src="{{ asset('img/profile.jpg') }}" alt="Foto de perfil" class="img-thumbnail">
                        </div>
                        <div class="bsc-tbl">
                            <table class="table table-bordered">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><b>Apellidos:</b></td>
                                        <td>Alexandra</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><b>Nombres:</b></td>
                                        <td>Madeleine</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><b>Sexo:</b></td>
                                        <td>Sebastian</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><b>Nivel:</b></td>
                                        <td>Elizabeth</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><b>Sección:</b></td>
                                        <td>Elizabeth</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><b>Correo de verificación:</b></td>
                                        <td>Benjamin</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><b>Correo estudiantil:</b></td>
                                        <td>Katherine</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Como ven está en un patrón de 6 columnas, lo que quisiera es lograr que se centre dejando 3 columnas a los lados y centrar esa imagen dentro del div que se encuentra, porque está pegada a la derecha, ya he tratado de poner margins y paddings en auto pero no funciona. No soy bueno manejando CSS por lo que no sé que otra cosa intentar a parte de eso.

[image: Así se encuentra actualmente]

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Bootstrap estás usando?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro es el template Notika, está usando Bootstrap v3.3.6

Comment: Tenés que usar [Offseting columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid-offsetting). Agregá `col-xs-offset-3` a la lista de clases de columnas. Con eso vas a mover todo 3 columnas para la derecha.

Comment: Magnífico, ¡muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero es agregar la clase `col-xs-offset-3` al listado de columnas. Con eso lográs empujar todo 3 columnas para la derecha ([offseting columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid-offsetting)).

Para centrar la imagen tenés que usar la clase `center-block` ([center content](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#helper-classes-center)).

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="normal-table-area">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 pd-x-auto col-xs-offset-3">
                <div class="normal-table-list">
                    <div class="basic-tb-hd">
                        <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/lego/2.jpg" alt="Foto de perfil" class="img-thumbnail center-block" width="64">
                    </div>
                    <div class="bsc-tbl">
                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><b>Apellidos:</b></td>
                                    <td>Alexandra</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><b>Nombres:</b></td>
                                    <td>Madeleine</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><b>Sexo:</b></td>
                                    <td>Sebastian</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><b>Nivel:</b></td>
                                    <td>Elizabeth</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><b>Sección:</b></td>
                                    <td>Elizabeth</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><b>Correo de verificación:</b></td>
                                    <td>Benjamin</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><b>Correo estudiantil:</b></td>
                                    <td>Katherine</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```